# how can i reduce dimension of matrix using SVD?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, dimensionality-reduction

-i try to reduce dimension of matrix using SVD in opencv c++
and this is my simple  source code example:

```
cv::Mat A = cv::Mat::zeros(8, 8, CV_32FC1); // all 0
A(Rect(1,1,4,4)) = 1;
Mat w;
SVD::solveZ(A,w);
cout<<w<<endl;
```

-but i don't know if this is a true method for reducing the  matrix dimension , i need your help.

Comment: Do you mean rank reduction?   
If so, take SVD leave just the first `k` eigen values and re-multiply to get the reduced rank matrix.

Comment: This is called *"Truncated SVD"*. See e.g. here: http://langvillea.people.cofc.edu/DISSECTION-LAB/Emmie%27sLSI-SVDModule/p5module.html